# Open a existing Account record in parent page in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

How to open a existing Account record in parent page itself instead of opens in a new popup window.

Pls.

Answer (score 2):

The [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx) shows you how to get the URL of a record, given the record ID.

Using JScript, you can set the current page location via `window.location` ([see here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)) thusly:

```
window.location = myNewUrl;
```